# How make dates list from date ranges with additional data on row in Google Sheets?

Tags: date, if-statement, google-sheets, sequence, textjoin

Issue:
Make table with fields "Member, Date, Rate" from table with fields "Member, Rate, From Date, To Date".

The result table must be fully automatically generated. (Using formulas: Arrayformula, Query and more)

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zKxao36tcbSniD2n8bFsUHR5EjrZHbYn2_xcl7sjM6Q/edit#gid=0):
Left side source table, right side result table.

Comment: Hi, do you have a formula you are working on? Also, would you consider using Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) for this?

Comment: i dont want use App Script, because i needs make sample for one doc type, and will using by not-professional users of Google Sheets.

Now i don't have a stable formula, because in all variants i had not automated solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF((A2:A5<>"")*(DAYS(D2:D5; C2:C5)>=SEQUENCE(1; 1000; 0)); 
 A2:A5&"×"&C2:C5+SEQUENCE(1; 1000; 0)&"×"&B2:B5; )); "×"); "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: This is magic! Fn!

How many hours you lost on this?)

Comment: @rollsover like 5 minutes